# Can't get UIImage to draw to the card front on the SuperCard example in cs193p

Tags: uiimage, cs193p

I'm doing the ITunesU cs193p course. I'm trying to get the following code to draw the image to the card front, as shown in the example from SuperCard, but for some reason the image is not being drawn to the UIView.  Some help would be appreciated.

```
//using an image for the face of the card, i'm going to look it up to see if it exists

if (self.faceUp){
    UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self rankAsString], self.suit]];

    NSLog(@"the faceImage is %@", faceImage);
    if (faceImage) {
    //i'm defining where and how big this is going to be   // the 1.0 - the scale factor, basically means 90% of the card size that i'm going to use
        CGRect imageRect =CGRectInset(self.bounds,
                                  self.bounds.size.width * (1.0-self.faceCardScaleFactor),
                                  self.bounds.size.height * (1.0-self.faceCardScaleFactor));

        [faceImage drawInRect:imageRect];

    } else {
        [self drawPips];
    }
```

I tried the following and got it to work using a dictionary:

```
if (self.faceUp){

    //renamed some png pictures and imported them into the Images.xcassets folder
    NSDictionary *cardImages=@{@"J":@"jack.png",@"Q":@"queen.png",@"K":@"king.png"};
    UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cardImages        valueForKey:[self rankAsString]]]];
    if (faceImage) {. . . .
```

But I'm still not sure why the earlier code didn't pull in the images. For example, the name of the king of hearts image as shown in the Image.Xassets is "K♥".  When I downloaded the code from the Stanford site, I also couldn't get it to draw the image to the view, so I'm wondering if others have had this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think I have selected different symbol or it was some sort of characters encoding issue. What fixed my problem was to rename the image with the same symbol I have inserted (copy-paste). Another decision is to get the same character from image filename and to use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This was because the suit if image name has different character set with the suit you use in the code. I renamed all image names with followed suit and it worked.

```
+ (NSArray *)validSuits
{
    return @[@"♥",@"♦",@"♠",@"♣"];
}
```